# Deleting an item from the shopping cart

Tags: android, expandablelistview, shopping-cart

I'm trying to delete a object from expandable list view. This code is in my adapter class.

```
                deleteIB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                        ShoppingCartEntry catalog = ShoppingCartHelper.getByProduct(cat);
                        Product selectedProduct = catalog.getProduct();
                        selectedProduct  = null;
                        _cartList.remove(groupPosition);
                        ProductAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
```

When I does this it will remove the item from the listview, but once open the cart activity again, I can find the added item in the cart. why is it behaving like that? Do I need to implement anything in my activity class.

**ShoppingCartHelper**

```
public static final String PRODUCT_INDEX = "PRODUCT_INDEX";
    private static Map<Product, ShoppingCartEntry> cartMap = new HashMap<Product, ShoppingCartEntry>();

    public static void setQuantity(Product product, int quantity) {
        // Get the current cart entry
        ShoppingCartEntry curEntry = cartMap.get(product);

        // If the quantity is zero or less, remove the products
        if (quantity <= 0) {
            if (curEntry != null)
                removeProduct(product);
            return;
        }

        // If a current cart entry doesn't exist, create one
        if (curEntry == null) {
            curEntry = new ShoppingCartEntry(product, quantity);
            cartMap.put(product, curEntry);
            return;
        }

        // Update the quantity
        curEntry.setQuantity(quantity);
    }

    public static int getProductQuantity(Product product) {
        // Get the current cart entry
        ShoppingCartEntry curEntry = cartMap.get(product);

        if (curEntry != null)
            return curEntry.getQuantity();

        return 0;
    }

    public static void removeProduct(Product product) {
        cartMap.remove(product);
    }

    public static List<Product> getCartList() {
        List<Product> cartList = new Vector<Product>(cartMap.keySet().size());
        for (Product p : cartMap.keySet()) {
            cartList.add(p);
        }

        return cartList;
    }

    public static ShoppingCartEntry getByProduct(Product product) {
        return cartMap.get(product);
    }
}
```

**ShoppingCartEntry**

```
private Product mProduct;
    private int mQuantity;

    public ShoppingCartEntry(Product product, int quantity) {
        mProduct = product;
        mQuantity = quantity;
    }

    public Product getProduct() {
        return mProduct;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return mQuantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        mQuantity = quantity;
    }

}
```

Comment: where did you store the cart's items ?

Comment: selectedProduct = null is useless in this context, you probably need something like catalog.removeProduct()

Comment: @Egor I got this error message, The method removeProduct() is undefined for the type ShoppingCartEntry

Comment: @Blackbelt i have updated my code, can U help wt it

Comment: @modabeckham, Well it's no surprise you get this error since you haven't specified this method. My comment was intended to point out that your logic of product removal is wrong and you need to re-think it.

Answer (score 1):

`catalog.getProduct()` returns the product you want (or the first, whatever your imlpementation is) and assigns a copy of that value to your variable `selectedProduct`. By giving it a null value, you nullify the copy of the product.

You should call `catalog.removeProduct` or something similar. Consider using the `ProductAdapter` to remove the product. The catalog will be updated automatically.

Answer (score 0):

the reason why the item is being added back to the cart is because you never called the method that will remove your product from the shopping cart. the only method you called was to remove the item from the listview. I see that you have ShoppingCartHelper.removeProduct(selectedProduct) method. You should call that too.

```
deleteIB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    ShoppingCartEntry catalog = ShoppingCartHelper.getByProduct(cat);
                    Product selectedProduct = catalog.getProduct();
                    ShoppingCartHelper.removeProduct(selectedProduct);
                    selectedProduct  = null;
                    _cartList.remove(groupPosition);
                    ProductAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
```

Comment: you need to create a method that would remove the product coming from the source. where are the products saved? is it saved in your sqlite? if so, you need to create a method that will delete the product from the sqlite. then make sure you call that method on your delete clicklistener